# Signed distance function from grayscale image

Tags: image-processing

I have a grayscale image and I would like to convert it to a signed distance function.

Right now I'm using `DistanceTransform` but I do not like the result.

```
image = Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "harbor.png"}]];
levelset = 
  ImageData[DistanceTransform[ColorNegate[image]] ] - 
   ImageData[DistanceTransform[image] ];
ListPlot3D[levelset]
```

`harbor.png`

[image]

`output`

[image]

You can clearly see the outline on the 3d plot which is really noisy, this is probably from the fact that `DistanceTransform` works on black&white images not on grayscale images.

What I really need is correct gradients near boundary but right now they are complete mess. Is there an easy way how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a "signed distance function"? BTW - DistanceTransform does not require a black and white image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How exact do you need the result to be? You could just binarize an upscaled version of the image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMQGZ.png"];    
b = Binarize[ImageResize[img, Scaled[8]], .5];
d = DistanceTransform[b] - DistanceTransform[1 - Dilation[b, 1]];
```

This yields relatively clean-looking gradients:

```
ListContourPlot[ImageData[d][[;; ;; 8, ;; ;; 8]]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[ImageData[d][[;; ;; 8, ;; ;; 8]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea to upscale and then downscale! This should suffice for my purpose.

Comment: Just a small improvement. You probably want to divide the result by `8`(or by whatever scaling factor you choose). At first I was a bit confused about the values I got.